# Android WebView can't display both video tags on WebRTC Peer connection

Tags: java, webview, android-webview, webrtc

I've created a Webview on android, with all required permissions on Manifest, and then I tried to display a site with a WebRTC peer connection sample. But it can't display both videos. It shows only the caller and not the recipients.

[Android Screen Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imOkg.png)

- website in WebView: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/
- Device: samsung SM-T280
- Android: 5.1.1
- API: 22
- ABI: armeabi-v7a
- Play Store:

  - Android System WebView: Version 73.0.3683.90

## Module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.webview"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

## Project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## MainActivity.java:

```java
package com.example.webview;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected WebView webView;
    protected Button button;
    protected WebSettings settings;

    @Override
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.web1);

        settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setMinimumFontSize(10);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }
        });
        webView.reload();
        webView.loadUrl("https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/");

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webView.reload();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## activity_main.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Refresh"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

    </WebView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

## AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.webview">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I expect both video tags to display the stream.

Comment: do you solve it??

Comment: @AmitSharma no I could not find an answer..

Comment: i also can't open it in the webView but for temporary solution i open it in default browser(Chrome) in chrome it's working fine.

Answer (score 5):

setting mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture as false fixed the issue for me.

```
settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture=false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I've been suffering from the same problem for days. I can get off work earlier today !

Comment: Strangely if this is not set to false even the simplest video cam sample is not working.
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor correction, it is -

```
settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

and not really -

```
settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture=false;
```